# How do I re-import a subreport into Crystal reports 9.0 without getting an Access Denied error?

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal Reports 9.0.  It has a subreport which is shared by 2 master reports.  I modified the subreport as a result of fixing one of the master reports.  When I try to re-import that subreport into my 2nd Master report I'm getting the error: Access denied then Re-importing the subreport failed.

Does anyone know what the problem might be?  The 2 master reports and subreport are all "checked" out so it's not a ready only issue.  Also when I first say re-import it tells me the file could not be found (pointing to a long dead file path) and I'm required to select it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have both the master reports open at the same time?

If so maybe closing the one you already refreshed, and trying it again. It seems like it has a lock on it for some reason.

Comment: I don't have the other master open at the same time so this shouldn't be an issue.